# URLSession | Authentication Challenge Response | NTLM

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, urlsession

I am aware of `How to Respond to an Authentication Challenge`like we have `NTLM Authentication` as there are 3 options.

- Provide authentication credentials.
- Attempt to continue without credentials.
- Cancel the authentication request.

But just want to know the thoughts here, when we go with the first option `Provide authentication credentials` we pass the username and password `URLCredential` is there any possibility of leakage of credentials, is it secure to pass the credentials, what is happening behind the screens? how `Apple` network API sending the credentials to the server?

Yes, we can set the policies like server domain, failure count etc. but from the security point of view is it safe? from Man in Middle Attack (`MIMA`) or anything else?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the way I have posted my question is not clear but I was looking more from the Application credential security point of view with [NTLM Authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYJEd.png) and after lots of Google, I have found, how’s NTLM works and it’s pretty interesting to see that client don’t share the password with the server. here are the steps as follow.

[image]

1. The client makes the request to the server.
2. The server needs to validate the user because there is no identity so server generates 16 bytes random number called as the challenge and sends it to the client.
3. Client hash this challenge with the user’s password and return it back to the server that is called the response it also includes username as plain text and challenge sent to the client.
4. The server sends everything to the domain controller and it uses the username to retrieve the hash of the user’s password from security account manager database and hash the challenge.
5. Domain controller shares the response back to the server if they are identical then authentication is successful otherwise a failure.

So the interesting part is here that Network API doesn’t share the password with the server it means it very secure.

I hope it will help others, [For More](https://bmnotes.com/2017/10/12/app-secure-urlsession-authentication-challenge-ntlm-security-credentails/).

Comment: So basically, it's digest auth with a shared secret, only with a server-provided nonce.  The big weakness of the scheme described above is that there's no secure way to update the password unless you have an encrypted channel (e.g. TLS), because it uses a shared the secret (the password) rather than a certificate that you can safely send to the server in the clear.

Comment: Oh, and it's also weaker than digest auth because only the 16-byte nonce is hashed for authentication rather than the entire request, which means it provides no protection against modification of submitted data in transit.  For that reason, I would not trust this authentication scheme over an unencrypted transport.

Comment: @dgatwood That's really nice to hear from you, can you please edit and these things with links into your answer it'll really help to the community. I also want to learn more here.

Comment: My bad.  Digest auth just encrypts a nonce, too.  I was thinking of an entirely different authentication scheme.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple types of challenges, and the answer to your question depends on what type of challenge you're talking about.  Each challenge has a **protection space**, which basically tells what type of challenge you're responding to.

To answer your question for the most common protection spaces:

- Basic password-based authentication (`NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic`): The credential you pass is sent in cleartext to the server (HTTP) or encrypted by the session key (HTTPS).
- Digest authentication (`NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPDigest`): The credential you pass is cryptographically hashed with a nonce provided by the server, and only the resulting hashed token gets sent over the network.
- NTLM authentication (`NSURLAuthenticationMethodNTLM`): The credential you pass is cryptographically hashed with a nonce sent by the server, and only the resulting hashed token gets sent over the network.
- **Client Certificate** authentication (`NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate`): The certificate is sent to the server, but not the private key data.  The client uses the private key to sign the prior TLS handshake data as a means of letting the server verify that the client really does have the private key associated with that cert.
- **Server** certificate **validation** (`NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust`): If you pass a certificate obtained from the server, you MUST validate it first, or else you effectively reduce the level of security to that of HTTP (i.e. any server can send any cert and you'll be saying to trust that cert when talking to the server).

The list above covers the most common protection spaces.  Kerberos is its own animal, and I don't know anything at all about how that works.   And there's also the "Form" protection space, which is just a placeholder for custom authentication that you can use in various parts of your app's code, but is not actually supported in any meaningful way.

It is worth noting that Basic, Digest, and NTLM authentication provide no protection against man-in-the-middle attacks if the attacker can alter data in transit, because the authentication token provided does not depend on the rest of the request in any way.  Thus, these are really suitable only for use over an encrypted channel (HTTPS).

Comment: +1 Thank you for your response. I am thinking about the credentials that we are sharing with the server when getting the challenge, is it safe or not. Maybe the way I have posted is not clear.

Comment: I've added info about NTLM here.  I also corrected the explanation of Digest auth.  I was confusing it with an encryption scheme that I came up with that does, in fact, hash the entire message using your key, thus making it largely immune to MITM except when creating an account/changing your password.  My bad.  :-)  Digest auth is basically very similar to NTLM.